# How to make endless business hours and constraints on FullCalendar JS?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have to create a calendar where the available and selectable hours are every day from 10:00 to 00:00.

When I'm passing this object to `businessHours`, `eventConstraint` and `selectConstraint`:

```
{
   startTime: "10:00:00",
   endTime: "00:00:00"
}
```

I have all the slots that are disabled. When I'm passing this one:

```
{
   startTime: "10:00:00",
   endTime: "23:59:59"
}
```

The calendar displays the right business hours, but I can't select the slot from 23:00 to 00:00 in any days.

How can I allow select this slot while having the right business hours, or just disable every days from 00:00 to 10:00 instead of allowing 10:00 to 00:00? I didn't find anything about disabling instead of enabling in the documentation.

I also tried an endless constraint like:

```
{
   startTime: "10:00"
}
```

But it didn't work. Hence, the question about endless constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: It kinds of seems like a bug in fullCalendar really - the `endTime` should probably assume it's midnight the next day if it's set to 00:00:00. I'd report it and see if they will fix it: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . There isn't much we can do for you at Stackoverflow on this one, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help though! I will try to contact them, I have a priority support with my account I think, or try to see if there's anything to patch in the lib otherwise opening an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, had an answer for this!

The `endTime` needs to be after `starTime` so we can use `"24:00:00"` to say midnight, instead of `"00:00:00"`

```
{
   startTime: "10:00:00",
   endTime: "24:00:00"
}
```

So it's not a bug, it's a feature.